# Does windows 10 Start menu support folders with custom icon?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, startmenu

I have my c# application where i create desktop.ini inside each folder to assign a custom icon to my folder. It works fine in windows 7.But in windows 10,it does not work.If I go to start menu path(C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs),there I am able to see the folder with custom icon,but in start menu view the folder always comes with default folder icon.

Folder "123" at the start menu path comes with the custom icon

[image]

Folder "123 at start menu comes with default folder icon"

[image]

Please suggest if there is any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a folder.jpg to the custom folder and set its attributes to system and hidden.

You can also create a shortcut to the folder and assign a custom icon to that.

I know the second option works with the windows UI.

Right-Click 
-New
-Shortcut
-Enter Folder Address
-Enter Name
-Save

Then Right-Click the Shortcut
-Properties
-Change Icon
-Choose Icon and Save

Then Right-Click Shortcut
-Add to start

So theoretically you should be able to create the folder, create a shortcut and assign the icon to that using the .ini file or you can at least take a look at what is different in comparing your application output and a shortcut made through the UI.  The start menu may have its own .ini file as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.Do you have any sample code snippets doing this?

Comment: Your second approach is for Start Menu Tiles,not for start menu.What I want is to create a folder with custom icon so that when I click on it,it should expand its contents instead of opening the folder in explorer.

Comment: I'm sorry don't have a sample this is purely based on using the UI and knowing of other applications out there that are used to customise start tiles.  There is a whole niche market for customising the start menu and normally it has to be done with an app so its changes made to the registry or system files that most people would not wan't to try to navigate.  Using .Net I would think you can access these features but you would need an understanding of how that works either from the programming side or from the config side.